# How to rename file without changing the modified date

Tags: r, file-rename

I wrote a script to rename files. But I found the modified date were changed to same. So the original order is broken if they are sorted by date. Is there any way to change the names without changing the modified date? Or although the dates are changed, the order is still the same if they are sorted by date. The following is my current code:

```
# save previous working folder
wkdir <- getwd()

# set the target folder
setwd("C:/Users/YY/Desktop/Tmp file/")

# set the file pattern
a <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "abc_*.*$") 

# set the name to be replaced
b<-gsub("abc_","ABC_",a)

# rename
file.rename(a,b)

# restore previous working folder
setwd(wkdir)
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Comment: This is not an `R` question. It's a question of what OS you are working under and what that OS allows for "modification" vs. "renaming".

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer for your question. It will help the people who are searching Stack Overflow about this problem to quickly find a proper solution.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question - I needed to process files, then archive. I tried in R first, then realized the copy changed the original datetime stamp for the file.

I eventually learned the shell() command and solved it with code like below. As I am in Windows OS, I used -R and -d in filenames to denote whether in form for R (/ form in path) or Windows (\ form in path) and converted using normalizePath().

```
sourcefileR <- "c:/Users/myname/Documents/test.dat"
destfileR <- "c:/Users/myname/Documents/somewhereelse/test.dat"
sourcefiled <- normalizePath(sourcefileR)
# now looks like: "c:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\test.dat"
destfiled <- normalizePath(destfileR)

rept <- shell(paste("copy ", sourcefiled, destfiled, sep=" "), intern=TRUE)
```

The intern parameter causes the OS feedback to go into the R object rept, which can be searched to find the "1 file(s) copied" string for success or whatever other error trapping you want.

I am in R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) on Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
running Windows 7 Professional, SP1.

Answer (score 6):

## The MOVE command and the program NIRCMD.

---

### MOVE

Instead of using a command like "REN" or "RENAME", you can also use the "MOVE" command for renaming your files and folders. The dates should stay the same.

Example:

> MOVE "C:\Folder\Filename.txt" "C:\Folder\New_Filename.txt"

*(I'm not perfectly sure if it works the same way on every versions of Windows, if you get a different result on a newer or older version of Windows, you can tell me by commenting.)*

---

### NIRCMD

Now, if for some reason the commands like REN or MOVE aren't the right solution for you, there is also a program named [Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) from Nirsoft that can do a LOT of stuff, including changing the file's dates to anything you want (Freeware).

You should definitely have this little program in your tool box.

Syntax:

> nircmd.exe setfiletime *"creation-time" "modified-time"*

Example:

> nircmd.exe setfiletime "C:\Folder\File.txt" "24-06-2003 17:57:11" "22-11-2005 10:21:56"

Comment: by the way changing filename in Explorer doesn't change modification date.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change names without changing the modification date. Think about that for a moment! You're modifying the file (even though you're not modifying the content).

Q. Are you sorting in R or outside in Windows folder view? 
Q. Have you thought about sorting by creation date?

If you're sorting in windows, you should be able to figure out how to sort by "Creation Date"
and if you're sorting it in R, use file.info to get relevant attributes and then sort on that.